# SQL Query. Join but in one table, each tuple has 2 occurrences of the joined attribute

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to display soccer match results that follow the format:

```
Team1Name Team1Score Team2Name Team2Score
```

where the tables are set up as:

Team(TeamID, TeamName)

Match_Results(TeamID1, Team1Score, TeamID2, Team2Score)

My initial intuition was to join them on TeamID since that is a shared attribute, but there are 2 occurrences of TeamIDs in the Match_Result table.

Answer (score 2):

You can join to the same table twice, like this:

```
select t1.team_name, team_1_score, t2.team_name, team_2_score
from match_results
inner join team t1 on team_id_1 = t1.id
inner join team t2 on team_id_2 = t2.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had no idea you could do designate your joins like that and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Tyler You're welcome. Please accept answer if it helped you.